# What is the best way to set/read UI values in Qt Quick

Tags: c++, qt, qml, qtquick2

I am writing a new C++ application and I decided to use Qt Quick instead of traditional Qt widgets, I know QML well but I am facing some trouble regarding the best way to read and set UI controls' values

in my application, it's called **DOO**, I have two QML files for each display, the first defines the UI elements and the second is a helper class to read/set UI values and it has a save() function to save to a database

for example lets take an object that is called **Son** and see how it is defined

in ***SonDisplay.qml***

```
import QtQuick 2.0
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

import DOO.Entities.Son 1.0
import DOOTypes 1.0

import "../UIElements"
import "../UIElements/DOOTheme.js" as DOOTheme
import "../DOO"

Display {

    id:sonDisplay

    contentHeight: 350
    contentWidth: 800

    // this is a QObject derived class, that I use as an entity to a table in a MySQL database
    // I use it here to set/read UI from/to it
    property Son son : Son{}
    property int disMode : DOO.Show
    property bool inEditMode : false
    ....
```

in the helper file ***SonHelper.qml***

```
    import QtQuick 2.0
import DOO.Commands.Son 1.0
import DOOTypes 1.0

QtObject {

    // read a Son object values into local son
    function readValues(pSon)
    {
        son.sonID = pSon.sonID
        son.name = pSon.name
        son.image = pSon.image
        son.age = pSon.age
        son.entryDate = pSon.entryDate
        son.commingFrom = pSon.commingFrom
        son.disabilityKind.kind = pSon.disabilityKind.kind
        son.caseDescription = pSon.caseDescription
        son.more = pSon.more
    }

    // copy local son values into a Son object
    function copyValues(pSon)
    {
        pSon.sonID = son.sonID
        pSon.name = son.name
        pSon.image = son.image
        pSon.age = son.age
        pSon.entryDate = son.entryDate
        pSon.commingFrom = son.commingFrom
        pSon.disabilityKind.kind = son.disabilityKind.kind
        pSon.caseDescription = son.caseDescription
        pSon.more = son.more

    }

    // read ui values into local son
    function readUIValues()
    {
        son.name = sonName.text
        son.image = sonImage.picture
        son.age = sonAge.text
        son.entryDate = Date.fromLocaleDateString(Qt.locale(), sonEntryDate.text, "dd-MM-yyyy")
        son.commingFrom = sonCommingFrom.text
        son.disabilityKind.kind = sonDisabilityKind.currentIndex
        son.caseDescription = sonCaseDescription.text
        son.more = sonMore.text

    }

    function validateUIValues()
    {
        if (Date.fromLocaleDateString(Qt.locale(), sonEntryDate.text, "dd-MM-yyyy") == "Invalid Date") return false
        //if(!sonSonID.acceptableInput) return false
        //if(!sonAge.acceptableInput) return false
        //if(!sonDisabilityKind.acceptableInput) return false

        return true
    }

    // save or update a son into database
    function save()
    {
        var v_son =  SonFactory.createObject()

        if (!validateUIValues())
        {
            dooNotifier.showMessage("Error","You Have some invalid input")
            return
        }

        readUIValues()
        copyValues(v_son) // copy local son values into v_son

        if(disMode === DOO.CreateNew)
        {
            if(SonCommands.insert(v_son))
            {
                dooNotifier.showMessage("Success","Son added successfully ")
                SonResultsModel.update()
                sonDisplay.hide()
            }
            else
            {
                dooNotifier.showMessage("Failed","Error adding son")
                DOOLogger.log(SonCommands.lasrErrorText())
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if(SonCommands.update(v_son))
            {
                dooNotifier.showMessage("Success","Son updated successfully ")
                SonResultsModel.update()
                sonDisplay.hide()
            }
            else
            {
                dooNotifier.showMessage("Failed","Error updating son")
                DOOLogger.log(SonCommands.lasrErrorText())
            }
        }

        v_son.destroy()
    }

}
```

As you can see, I use a function to read a Son object values into local son object, a second one to copy local son object's values into a Son object, and a third function to read UI values into local son object

Now I am wondering if is there any better way to handle this scenario instead of *readValues(pSon)*, *copyValues(pSon)*, and *readUIValues()* functions

or this is a good pattern to do that

***Edit***

I think I could use a QAbstractItemModel derived class to read/ save to databaase and pass UI values to it as a JavaScript object or read UI values into local son object and pass it to a C++ save() function that will validate and save data like this:

```
    var uivalues = {
    name : sonName.text ,
    image : sonImage.picture ,
    age : sonAge.text ,
    entryDate : Date.fromLocaleDateString(Qt.locale(), sonEntryDate.text, "dd-MM-yyyy") ,
    commingFrom : sonCommingFrom.text ,
    disabilityKind : sonDisabilityKind.currentIndex ,
    caseDescription : sonCaseDescription.text ,
    more : sonMore.text ,
    }

    SonResultsModel.save(uivalues)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***First*:**

I think you should move more logic to the C++ code. For the best performance it's better to use minimum js code as possible.

Create your son as C++ class with properties then bind this properties to UI if it's possible.

***Second:***

Last method in helper class **save()** could be in the special class. That can be usefull when you use more classes like son because the work with that classes will be simillar.

**EDIT:**

I think it's better now. See comments below.

Comment: sure, I think I could create a js object with all UI values as properties and pass it to c++ to save it using a QAbstractItemModel derived class, have a look at my question again to see changes